# How do I make a save button that will make a .html file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a code tester and I was wondering how do I make a save button for my code tester. My intent is to make it save as a .html file in the "u" directory on my site then shows them the link to the saved code. Here is my code:

```
                    <iframe src="menu-bar.html" height="45" width="1300" align="right" scrolling="no" frameborder="0"></iframe>
                    <br />
                    <br />
                    <br />
                            <!-- Code Tester Starts -->
        <div class="center-page">
        <!-- Code Tester Scripts Starts -->
                    <script src="http://jswebsite.co.nf/code-tester-javascript.min.js"></script>
        <!-- Code Tester Scripts End -->
                    <p>If you press Ctrl + Enter, the code will open in a new tab. If you press the "Test HTML Code" button, the code will open in a new window if you are using a Chrome browser.
                    <br />Please resize the code box if needed.</p>
        <p style="font-size:23px; color: white;">Code Tester for HTML:</p>
    <form name="tester">
    <textarea rows="20" cols="120" name="code-box" wrap="physical" id="codebox" spellcheck="false"></textarea>
            <br />
            <input type="button" value="Test HTML Code" onclick="preview()">
            <input value="Clear HTML Code" type="reset">
            <button onclick="TogetherJS(this); return false;">Collaborate</button>
        </form>
                    </div>
                    <!-- Code Tester Ends -->
```

Comment: Unless you use the File API, you can't save files to the client's computer. I'm not even sure if the API allows saving actually.

Comment: There is no _easy_ way (without a hack like in @moisrex's answer) you can do this by triggering ctrl + s keydown events because of security reasons.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use this function:

```
function save(filename, html) {
  var el = document.createElement('a');
  el.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/html;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(html));
  el.setAttribute('download', filename);
  el.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(el);
  el.click();
  document.body.removeChild(el);
}
```

usage:

```
save('test.html', '<html></html>');
```

Comment: This is a hack way imo but this is the best shot too. Emitting ctrl + s with keydown events is not supported because of security reasons so...

Comment: @sotn even if we could push `Ctrl + S` for user, it wouldn't be a good way. User may have put some JS code that messes with the html and Ctrl + S would save those changes too. And it was much more pain for @Joshua to enter the window and press the Ctrl + S.

Comment: Sorry, but I just edited the description. I want it to save on the "u" directory that I made on my site then show them the link that will take them to the saved file. Example: http://jswebsite.co.nf/u/1.html

Comment: @Joshua saving it in your server is not JS's job description. you need to do it with server side programming languages like PHP, ASP.NET, JAVA, PYTHON, etc. only part that you would need javascript is ajax for sending the html code for the server.

Answer (score 1):

Im not 100% sure what you are looking for but if the html file is already known you can set a download attribute to it in an  tag like [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_a_download)

`<a href="/test.html" download>`